# League of legends gold border

Tags: league-of-legends

So I'm in gold 5, and I don't have a gold border like the other people I know have.
I don't know if I should go to a higher rank gold or what
How do I get the gold border?

Answer (score 8):

You will get your border at the official end of season 4. This will happen on November 11, 2014 as Damek has already pointed out in his answer. Like every season, you will only get the border of your Ranking **in a specific Queue**. Any change of your ranking that happens after this date **will be ignored**. This means if you are Gold 1 and in the promotion to platinum you won't get the Platinum rewards if you reach Plat on November 12.

This basically means: If you are gold in Twisted Treeline ranked teams, your border will **not** show up in Summoners rift (Same goes the other way around). However your highest rated border will be shown on the Crystal Scar and on The Howling Abyss.

**Please note that you will not recieve your Rewards if you are chat-restricted or otherwise banned/often reported**.

Also your ranking in previous Season has **absolutely no effect** on the rewards of Season 4. For example (as Philipp pointed out in his comment) If you were Platinum in season 3 and Gold in season 4, your platinum Border will be replaced with a Gold border. Of course you still have the Permanent rewards like the Victorious Skin and the Summoners Icon.

Comment: can you also answer what happens when you were plat in S3 and you will be gold in S4? (both solo queue)

Comment: @PhilippSander Sure. I'll just edit the answer to a more general thing about the EOS-Rewards.

Comment: I wouldn't say S3 has *absolutely no effect* on S4 as Qualifiers are half determined by your prior season's performance. But I guess that's an indirect effect so you wouldn't be wrong with your current statement.

Answer (score 2):

The border you have on the loading screans shows the division you were in in the last season, not the current season.

**Example:**

> Last season I Finished the season in Silver V so right now I have a
>   silver border even though I am in gold V now. When the season ends on
>   11 November I will get the golden border.

```
The 2014 season ends on November 11, 2014 at 12:01 AM PST
```

Read [this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/competitive/end-season-rewards-and-new-master-tier) page for more information.

**Edit:**(thanks to Jeykey)

The border displayed is from the divison you were in last season. If you got to Diamond in S3 you've had an Diamond border in Season 4. If you only managed to get to Platinum in S4 you will get a Platinum border next season.

Comment: Is the border tied to the previous season or your best season ever? If you were gold 2 seasons ago, but silver last season, will you have a silver or gold border?

Comment: The border shows your rating of the last season.
(No border = unranked)

Comment: Is it the rank at which you are when the season ends, or the highest rank you got during the season that is counting ?

Comment: @Shunwoo The rank at which you are when the season ends.